# input type="number" with currency formatting (thousands delimiters)

Tags: html

This has already been asked numerously and lots of examples have been provided, either with tons of JavaScript, or using the `inputmode` or the `pattern` attribute with some regex. However, none of these seem to work together with the numeric keyboard (at least not on my iPhone).

Therefore my question: is this impossible? *(in plain and simple HTML5)*

I need an `<input>` for currency with on-the-fly formatting, to edit numbers like this: `1,000,000.00` or, when changing the country, to `1 234 567,89` **AND** the numeric keyboard appears (important for mobiles). Notice the thousands separators.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: How did you make this work? The chosen answer does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only HTML5 will not work today. (6-6-2016)

What you *want* is this:

```html
<input type="text" pattern="your-pattern" inputmode="numeric">
```

However, [`inputmode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-inputmode) is not supported in any browser yet.

The code above explained:

- We can't use `type="number"` because the `pattern` attribute is not supported on that type, so we use `type="text"`. A better choice might be `type="tel"` because it's also concerned with numbers and delimiters. However, I don't know the semantic implications of this (on SEO and screenreaders for instances). The safest approach is `text`
- `inputmode` is new and allows you to specify what kind of input mode is required. Especially useful for mobile devices, as you can imagine

Considering you want to have on the fly conversion from one standard notation to another, you will have to use JavaScript so you can use it for your pattern validation if you really want to use a `number` type. Or maybe there is even another public API to control the keyboard through JS (but I doubt it, may cause security issues).

Finally, as always: if your validation is important, do it server-side. The client-side should never be trusted. (Even if they have cookies.)

Comment: as instructive as your answer is, it does not really answer the question, he never spoke of any kind of validation. Thank you tho, I learned some useful things